# tab auto completion not working (/etc/bash_completion not working)?

Tags: bash

i am on an old ubuntu environment (Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS) and bash_completion is not working even i included it in my .bashrc:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
. /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

i tried including /etc/bash_bashrc, but still not working:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_bashrc ]; then
. /etc/bash_bashrc
fi

user@old_skunk:~:$ cd loca-bash: exclude: unbound variable

user@old_skunk:~:$ls -al loca-bash: !ref: unbound variable
-bash: !ref: unbound variable
-bash: !ref: unbound variable
-bash: words[i]: unbound variable
```

Comment: is this definitely bash, not sh or something? `echo $SHELL`?

Comment: user@old_skunk:~:$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

Comment: This happens to me when I've done `set -u`; seems there's an undefined variable somewhere in .bash_completion. `set +u` makes the problem go away but I'd prefer if I didn't get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the contents of the file `/etc/bash_completion` and then check if there is any file such as `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` is getting sourced from there?

If not, then the bash_completion script itself is not there or damaged?

Comment: @meatspace: user@old_skunk:~:$ ls -al /usr/share/bash-completion
ls: cannot access /usr/share/bash-completion: No such file or directory

Comment: It seems that bash-completion script is damaged. Can you please try to reinstall it using the command: **sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash-completion**

Comment: user@old_skunk:~:$  ls -al /etc/bash_completion
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 58753 May 10  2013 /etc/bash_completion

Comment: Can you please post the contents of the file /etc/bash_completion ?
Also, did you reinstall bash-completion?

Comment: well, it is company jump station and i don't have authority to do anything except using it. the script /etc/bash_completion is there.

Comment: OK! Atleast, can you see post the output of **cat /etc/bash_completion** ?

Comment: yes. but i think it might be too big to post it on this forum?

Comment: i actually tried to put bash_completion from 16.4.04 under my home directory but a bunch errors: -bash: [: too many arguments
-bash: [: =: unary operator expected
-bash: [: =: unary operator expected
-bash: [: =: unary operator expected
-bash: [: =: unary operator expected
-bash: [: too many arguments
-bash: [: =: unary operator expected
-bash: [: =: unary operator expected
-bash: [: =: unary operator expected
-bash: [: =: unary operator expected
-bash: [: =: unary operator expected

Answer (score 0):

I used this script and everything is well

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash-completion
```